# How to ensure that a thread gets maximum priority?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have a buffer where many threads will be writing ( decrementing the count of CountDownLatch per each write). I also have a thread(lets call it main thread) waiting on the same CountDownLatch instance.  Is there anyway I can ensure that main thread is the one that gets scheduled immediately,once count reaches zero ?  Does giving max priority to the main thread work ? Or is there any other robust way ?

Comment: So you essentially want highest priority to thread which is waiting on condition? That does not make much sense. Are you facing some issues because this thread has "too low priority" ?

Comment: Here is the actual requirement , as sson as the required number of msgs are there in the buffer i need to push them to some other location  and this is the activity that should happen first. So the thread that does this has to preempt every other thread.

Comment: `So the thread that does this has to preempt every other thread.` - instead of fiddling with OS scheduler semantics you should use proper synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we create a thread in Java, it always has some priority assigned to it. Priority can either be given by JVM while creating the thread or it can be given by programmer explicitly.

Accepted value of priority for a thread is in range of 1 to 10. There are 3 static variables defined in Thread class for priority:
1. public static int **MIN_PRIORITY**: This is minimum priority that a thread can have. Value for this is 1.
2. public static int **NORM_PRIORITY**: This is default priority of a thread if do not explicitly define it. Value for this is 5.
3. public static int **MAX_PRIORITY**: This is maximum priority of a thread. Value for this is 10.

```
 ThreadDemo t1 = new ThreadDemo();
 t1.setPriority(2);

 // Main thread  
 System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
 System.out.println("Main thread priority : " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());

 // Main thread priority is set to 10
 Thread.currentThread().setPriority(10);
 System.out.println("Main thread priority : " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your requirement i.e. when the required number of messages are there in the buffer, these messages needs to be pushed to some other location. What you can do is to create some sort of listener on the buffer which polls/listens to the state of the buffer and when the desired state is reached you can make other threads to relinquish control(which can be done through the concept of yielding), then thread scheduler will look for other thread of equal or higher priority and will give processor to that thread(which should be the thread that push messages to other location) and other threads will move to Ready/Runnable state.

Answer (score 0):

I think by saying maximum priority you meant you want to reduce the overhead of thread dispatching as much as possible when a certain barrier/threshold is reached. This is what CyclicBarrier is designed for, i.e., right after it reaches the barrier a callback gets invoked.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-concurrent-cyclicbarrier-java/

Comment: Yes ,but I don't want all other threads to wait after reaching the barrier , they have to continue running. With CyclicBarrier there is no way to keep other threads in the party running.